# Django Admin add support for HEIC for ImageField

Tags: python, django, django-admin, heic, heif

please has someone experience with adding support of new image formats to the Django Admin module? I want to use this one called pyheif-pillow-opener [pyheif-pillow-opener](https://pypi.org/project/pyheif-pillow-opener/) for HEIC support. It should be registered, but I am not sure where exactly. I tried to install that module and then in Django Admin upload an image to ImageField, but still, I am getting a message:

> Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.

**EDIT - Solution:**

There is only need to add to a used Django applications **admin.py** file these lines of code:

```
from pyheif_pillow_opener import register_heif_opener

register_heif_opener()
```

Comment: Where/how are you registering the opener?

Comment: I forget about this registration, thank you for that comment, because without that I would not try it ...

Answer (score 0):

Another solution(add it to **admin.py** as TS suggest):

```
try:
    from pillow_heif import HeifImagePlugin
except ImportError:
    HeifImagePlugin = None # here you can log a warning
```